# In the new profile page, why tag badges are not considered to be notable?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page, tag-badges

Why tag badges are not included in "notable badges" section? I have two notable tag badges (both were awarded only 10 times). But "Informed" (awarded 15 times) is still shown as most notable. I understand that they are mentioned in the "top tags" section, but anyway, they are notable.

Comment: If *Informed* is a notable badge on Meta, I would strongly guess that rareness strongly plays into notability.

Comment: @Wrz yeah, notableness there is rareness of badge.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft good point, so is the bronze [Proofreader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/155/proofreader) - only 31 of those on MSE cause it to be notable for some users with many gold badges, e.g. [Oded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded?tt=profile).